# Adding plots in between faceted plots with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(Z = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
    Y = c(0.12, 4, 1, 8, 0.25, 4, 0.06, 0.06, 8, 0.5, 0.12, 0.5, 
    0.06, 8, 16, 0.25, 0.12, 0.25, 4, 8), n = c(20L, 1L, 4L, 
    6L, 45L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 28L, 7L, 
    28L, 1L, 6L), X = c("E", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B", "E", "F", 
    "F", "A", "D", "F", "E", "B", "B", "B", "F", "E", "B", "D"
    ), value = c(14, 1, 1, 0, 45, 0, 3, 0, 0, 9, 0, 4, 3, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 26, 0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

I use the following code to create these two plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_data, aes(X, factor(Y), fill = value))+
  geom_tile(color = "white")+
  facet_wrap(~Z, ncol = 2)+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(factor(Y), n))+
  geom_col()+
  facet_wrap(~Z)+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

What I want to do is to put each of the faceted plots next to one another, and shorten the width of the barplot one, something like this:

[image]

I saw that the [ggExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggExtra/README.html) package had something similar, but that only works with scatterplots. Is there any way of visualizing the amount of each category on the y-axis in a similar manner?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with facets as you're trying to put different classes (numeric and factor) on the same scale.

Comment: @PoGibas It doesn't necessarily have to be done that way - I simply want to create a plot which visualize this. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear it!

Comment: @Haakonkas it sounds like you want to add [marginal histograms](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/277-marginal-histogram-for-ggplot2/), albeit for a tiled heatmap rather than scatterplot. Is that right? (I'd strongly advise against using `facet_wrap` in that case though, `facet_grid(Z ~ .)` would do a much better job at keeping marginals on the margins).

Comment: @Z.Lin I tried doing this, but it doesn't really give me what I want. I only want the bars on the right hand side - and when i tried it I only got an error: Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function `grid.arrange()` from `gridExtra` package (nice explanation [here])[1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html). This allows you to take separately plotted plots and then arrange them in a consistent grid and adjust the size of each plot individually if needed. For this to work you would need to plot each one of your facets separately and then pass them to the package.

Assuming that each of your facets is called something like A1 for top left, B4 for bottom left. Your code would look something like this:

```
grid.arrange(
   grobs = c(Al:B4)
   widths = c(2, 1, 2, 1),
   layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                         c(5, 6, 7, 8))
)
```

Using this format, you would individually label your plots so as to overcome the difference in types of scale.